# The version of redmine is Compatible with redmine-java-api

Tags: redmine, redmine-api

I use Redmine-java-api to connect to redmine and I get some errors. I think the cause is version of redmine and redmine-java-api.

So about my question, I don't know what's the version of redmine is Compatible with another version of Redmine-java-api? Anyone can help me list the version of Redmine and version of Redmine-java-api is Compatible. 
Ex: redmine-java-api v1.25 -> redmine v?

Sorry for my bad in English.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give us link to that java API and dump of your errors?

Comment: Hi Aleksandar Pavić, 
I'm using java api v1.25 and error when the redmine v3.2.
But my expected is list version of java-api is compatible with version redmine.
Example: 
 - redmine-java-api v1.25 -> redmine ver.x-ver.y
 - redmine-java-api v2.0 -> redmine ver.t-ver.z